# What is the resonant frequency of ice? How could you calculate the resonant frequency of ice for a cylinder of ice?

Tags: water, frequency, resonance, ice

Can vibrating frequencies break apart the structure of ice? Or could electromagnetic frequencies do the same?

Comment: Resonant to what? What structure of ice?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

for low amplitudes, the answers are No and No.

The mechanical resonant frequency of a *piece* of ice depends on its *physical dimensions*, its *stiffness*, and its *mass per unit volume*. "Ice" by itself has no mechanical resonant frequency until you specify its length, width and thickness.